# How Google Doc intercepts Ctrl - S / Command - S to save the document not the html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-docs

I am trying to introduce this into my project, I did some search but here https://github.com/RobertWHurst/KeyboardJS/issues/19 I found that it looks quite hard to intercept these meta keys.

So I am curious how google doc does that? Is it a different way from using just javascript?

Comment: If you checkout KeyboardJS again it handles the super keys much better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried?

Here's a fiddle (that I found in google, took me about 10 seconds) that is intercepting those events using common methods:
http://jsfiddle.net/GBuBj/

taken from here: http://www.scottklarr.com/topic/126/how-to-create-ctrl-key-shortcuts-in-javascript/
and here: https://superuser.com/questions/120672/mediawiki-assign-ctrl-s-to-save-page-edit-mode

Win key is different story, but CTRL is fine (except maybe CTRL+ESC and couple of similar shortcuts that are used by OS).

Comment: hey ;-) /me is waving from the building across the road

Comment: @zerkms small world, eh? :)))

Comment: sorry that I didn't dig further when I see that issue on KeyboardJS. Thanks for the answers and it's amazing to see the small world happend . :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not difficult at all. You just bind to document and listen for `keydown`: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/DVmDs/ (just assume your document is the bottom right block and click it once before you press `ctrl+s`)

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 83 && e.ctrlKey) {
        alert('you have pressed ctrl+s');
    }
});​
```